# Best way to make tiles not have borders in between them?

Tags: c++, sfml

So I am trying to make a game using SFML and visual c++. Currently I have different sprites without borders on certain sides for every combination of tiles that could be bordering each other, then used nested if statements to check which sprite to use. However, this slows down my game to the point where I can't even play it. Is there a better way to do this?

Here is my code:

```
//Render tiles
            for (int i = 0; i < blockX.size(); i++) {
                    block.setPosition(float(blockX[i]), float(blockY[i]));
                    if (blockType[i] == "metal") {
                            //if block is metal tile
                            block.setTexture(metalBlockSingle);
                            if (doesBlockExist(blockX[i] + 20, blockY[i])) {
                                    //if block is to right
                                    if (doesBlockExist(blockX[i], blockY[i] + 20)) {
                                            //if block is below
                                            if (doesBlockExist(blockX[i] - 20, blockY[i])) {
                                                    //if block is to left
                                                    if (doesBlockExist(blockX[i], blockY[i] - 20)) {
                                                            //if block is above
                                                            block.setTexture(metalBlockCenter);
                                                    }
                                                    else {
                                                            block.setTexture(metalBlockBottomRightLeft);
                                                    }
                                            }
                                            else if (doesBlockExist(blockX[i], blockY[i] - 20)) {
                                                    //if block is above
                                                    block.setTexture(metalBlockTopBottomRight);
                                            }
                                            else {
                                                    //if block is neither above nor to left
                                                    block.setTexture(metalBlockBottomRight);
                                            }
                                    }
                                    else if (doesBlockExist(blockX[i] - 20, blockY[i])) {
                                            //if block is to left
                                            if (doesBlockExist(blockX[i], blockY[i] - 20)) {
                                                    //if block is above
                                                    block.setTexture(metalBlockTopRightLeft);
                                            }
                                            else {
                                                    block.setTexture(metalBlockRightLeft);
                                            }
                                    }
                                    else if (doesBlockExist(blockX[i], blockY[i] - 20)) {
                                            //if block is above
                                            block.setTexture(metalBlockTopRight);
                                    }
                                    else {
                                            //if block is only right
                                            block.setTexture(metalBlockRight);
                                    }
                            }
                            else if (doesBlockExist(blockX[i], blockY[i] + 20)) {
                                    //if block is below
                                    if (doesBlockExist(blockX[i] - 20, blockY[i])) {
                                            //if block is to left
                                            if (doesBlockExist(blockX[i], blockY[i] - 20)) {
                                                    //if block is above
                                                    block.setTexture(metalBlockTopBottomLeft);
                                            }
                                            else {
                                                    //if block is not above
                                                    block.setTexture(metalBlockBottomLeft);
                                            }
                                    }
                                    else {
                                            //if block is not to left
                                            if (doesBlockExist(blockX[i], blockY[i] - 20)) {
                                                    //if block is above
                                                    block.setTexture(metalBlockTopBottom);
                                            }
                                            else {
                                                    //if metal block is not above
                                                    block.setTexture(metalBlockBottom);
                                            }
                                    }
                            }
                            else if (doesBlockExist(blockX[i] - 20, blockY[i])) {
                                    //if block is to left
                                    if (doesBlockExist(blockX[i], blockY[i] - 20)) {
                                            //if block is above
                                            block.setTexture(metalBlockTopLeft);
                                    }
                                    else {
                                            block.setTexture(metalBlockLeft);
                                    }
                            }
                            else if (doesBlockExist(blockX[i], blockY[i] - 20)) {
                                    //if block is above
                                    block.setTexture(metalBlockTop);
                            }
                    }
                    window.draw(block);
            }
```

EDIT: Here is the code for the "doesBlockExist" function:

```
bool doesBlockExist(int x, int y) {
    bool returnVal =  false;
    int findX = int(round(x / 20) * 20);
    int findY = int(round(y / 20) * 20);
    for (int i = 0; i < blockX.size(); i++) {
        if (blockX[i] == findX && blockY[i] == findY) {
            returnVal = true;
        }
    }
    return(returnVal);

    return(true);
}
```

Comment: Use a profile to find out where most of your execution time is spent.

Comment: This is the part where most of my execution time is spent.

Comment: Is `doesBlockExist` expensive? It's called a lot.

Comment: @cppguy I edited it to include the function.

Comment: It looks like you need to redesign this logic. It looks incredibly expensive for what you're trying to do. You're nesting looping over blockX.size(). There's almost certainly a way to just check the surrounding 8 tiles to determine your texture.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you have nested if-statements (high [cyclomatic complexity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclomatic_complexity)) like this, you should immediately stop and think about other designs. Large nested if-statements are not only prone to contain mistakes, but are impossible to really understand at a glance.

A better design can start with splitting things into multiple function, each with their own [single responsibility](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle). Other steps involve thinking about the logic hard enough to find ways that eliminate conditions, i.e. when situation X holds up, Y follows and there's no need for further checking. And then there are also situations where instead of using if-statements you can construct an object that will have the right settings after construction.

As for optimizations on your code:

- Use a sprite sheet and don't use x amount of textures. `setTextureRect` is basically a free function, while switching textures all the time, can lead to performance issues.
- If you keep the implementation of `doesBlockExist`, at least make sure to return right when you find the block and don't keep iterating. This means, inside the if-body just write `return true` and after the loop write `return false` and delete the variable returnVal.
- However the `doesBlockExist` function seems badly implemented. What exactly does it check for? Do you just check the surrounding tiles? If so, then you can easily just check the 8 surrounding tiles and don't need to iterate over all the tiles.
- Since you call `doesBlockExist` quite often, you'll have to think about, whether it wouldn't be possible to just call it once and report on all the surrounding tiles at once.
- `int(round(x / 20) * 20);` since x is already `int` `x / 20` will be an integer division anyways, so there's no reason to round.

Alternatively you could just use a tile editor like Tiled and place the tiles accordingly when designing the level and then just load the tile map.

As for the question in the title, I have no idea what you mean with borders.